# What is the relationship between the eigenvectors of a matrix, and the angle of the eignevectors?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix that is the canonical [1,0][0,1] -- rotated 30 degrees, and scaled with [2,0][0,.5].

I am curious to know why the eigenvectors of this matrix lose their orthogonality. My understanding is that the eigenvalues are what that bring the determinant to 0, and that the eigenvectors, when multiplied by the original matrix, are only scaled versions. So wherein this process does orthogonality get lost?

I am curious about this in the contest of eigendecompositions. Given $A = PDP^{-1}$, I  see that AD is a scaled version of A. But I don't understand why plotting P alone reveals vectors with a new angle. I suspect symmetry of vectors has something to do with all this, but I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The characterization that eigenvectors “lose their orthogonality” doesn’t really make sense to me. _Every_ nonzero vector is an eigenvector of the identity matrix, so most of them aren’t orthogonal to begin with. Are you asking why some matrices don’t have orthogonal eigenvectors? That’s a bit much to expect when some don’t have any (real) eigenvectors at all, or only have eigenvectors that are multiples of a single vector.

Comment: I’ll also add that if you’re thinking that this sequence of transformations somehow destroys orthogonality of eigenvectors, consider that if you leave out the scaling and simply rotate through some angle that’s not a multiple of $\pi$, there are no (real) eigenvectors at all—the rotation has somehow “destroyed” them. How then, does an additional scaling restore them? All in all, I’m not sure that this is a fruitful way to think about what eigenvectors represent.

Comment: If A can be decomposed to a stretch and rotate, and these decompositions are solely eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Why is one of the parts of the decomposition nonorthogonal, given that the original matrix was orthogonal? I would suspect that the decomposed pieces would simply be stretches and rotations, which would not have an effect on orthogonality. But in fact, the decomposed pieces of A, are not orthogonal on their own, but reconstructed are orthogonal. I find this unintuitive, and wonder if you have a more intuitive way to think about this?

Comment: It’s still unclear to me what exactly it is that you’re talking about being orthogonal here. Is there some specific decomposition that you’re wondering about? There’s certainly no good reason to expect in general that eigenvectors of a product of matrices (if any!) have any particular relationship to the eigenvectors of the individual matrices.

Comment: The eigenvectors of {{ 1.73205081, -0.25},{ 1.        ,  0.4330127 }}. 

I am not expecting that eigenvectors of a product of matrices have a relationship with the eigenvectors of individual matrices, in general. I am expecting that they do, for an eigendecomposition.